# Parsing python output

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

Hey guys how can i parse this output in Python:

```
 /abc{3,}zz/
         the quick brown fox
 No match

 /The quick brown fox/i
         the quick brown fox
  0: the quick brown fox

 /a*abc?xyz+pqr{3}ab{2,}xy{4,5}pq{0,6}AB{0,}zz/
         the quick brown fox
 No match
```

to get this string "/The quick brown fox/i"

I considered using something like foo.find("0:") but from there I can't think of how to get the line above this should be pretty simple thanks for the help!

Comment: What exactly is the input? Whats wrong with foo.find('/The quick brown fox/i')?

Comment: the input is the one big string. I want the line that is 2 lines above a line that starts with "0:"

Comment: Read all lines into list `lines`, find on list line with '0:' and then `lines[index-2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering based on your comment:

> the input is the one big string. I want the line that is 2 lines above a line that starts with "0:"

The approach is:
1. Create a list holding each line, 2. Find lines which start with `0:`, not counting leading whitespace (`strip` will remove trailing and leading whitspace), 3. Print the number of the line two lines above any match

```
inputstr="""/abc{3,}zz/
        the quick brown fox
No match

/The quick brown fox/i
        the quick brown fox
 0: the quick brown fox

/a*abc?xyz+pqr{3}ab{2,}xy{4,5}pq{0,6}AB{0,}zz/
        the quick brown fox
No match"""

inputlst=inputstr.split('\n')
for i in range(2,len(inputlst)):
    if inputlst[i].strip().startswith('0:'):
        print(i - 1)
```

This will print `5`. It also assumes Line `1` and `2` don't start with `'0:'`.